# Querying a Table which contains names of view

Tags: sql

I have a primary Table **EXPORTER** which has 3 columns col_1, col_2 and view_name.

I need to be able to get the list of all the column_names and their datatypes from all the view_name(s) in the EXPORTER table.

I know how to get the list of column names and their data types from a view using :

```
SELECT
    Column_Name, Data_Type
FROM
    ALL_TAB_COLUMNS
WHERE
    TABLE_NAME = 'view';
```

But having difficulty figuring out how to combine the primary table and all the views.

Comment: So, you want to display all of your "view" data that in EXPORTER table?

Comment: I got my answer I could write the query as shown below:                        select a.filetype, a.reportname, b.column_name, b.data_type
from exporter a, all_tab_columns b
where a.viewname = b.table_name;